# Unused function in macro with clang

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I have a `macro` that is defined as the following, ie:

```
#define next_position() (bit ? *str++ : (*str++) & 0xff)

warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
```

`Clang` is saying the first `*str++` is being unused in the macro, but `gcc` never displayed this 'warning' to me, is this a compiler bug? 
how can I work around it? It seems like a legitimate warning.

Comment: Where are you using `next_position`? Are you just writing `next_position();` without using the expression result? `clang`, like any other C compiler, doesn't complain about macros themselves, only macro instantiations.

Comment: In say, help.c, I'm just calling it like next_position()

Comment: What I'm getting at is this: are you using the output of `next_position`? If you aren't, then the warning makes perfect sense. It's not warning about `*str++`, but about `next_position` as a whole.

Comment: I ended up just doing this next_position(*str++) and getting rid of some rough calls in my code. Thanks!

Comment: Casting to void, as in `(void)(bit ? *str++ : (*str++) & 0xff)` would take care of it.

Comment: Note that if you never use the result of the expression (and never intend to), then you can just change the macro to: `#define next_position() ((void)(++str))`.  Or just cut out the middleman, and use `++str` directly instead of the macro. Of course, all this only applies *if* the macro will never be used in other ways.

Comment: Remember that the ternary operator is an _expression_. Expressions returns _values_. clang is simply telling you that you are using an expression without using its returned value, i.e. you use the expression for its side-effects not to use the returned value. Like others suggested, casting the whole expression to `void` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Clang is correct -- you are dereferencing str, but are not using its value.
If all you want is to advance str, then next_position would boil down to:

```
#define next_position() str++
```

It would bring the question why you would want to hide *that* behind a macro, but that's a different issue.

As for getting warning from clang, but not gcc, they are different compilers. They are detecting overlapping but not identical set of potential issues with the code and they are pedantic in somewhat different ways. Even gcc itself produces different sets of warnings depending on optimization level and gcc version. The fact that one compiler produces a warning but another does not does not necessarily mean that there's a bug in the compiler. Nor does it say anything whether there's really a problem in your code. It's just an indication that something *may* be off.